# Securely Encrypt And Store Password in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm attempting to encrypt and decrypt a user's password inside core data using the transformable attribute type. Here's my `NSValueTransformer` subclass:

```
@objc (PasswordTransformer) class PasswordTransformer: NSValueTransformer {
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return NSData.self
    }

    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    override func transformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        if let string = value as? String {
            let tuple = Utils.encryptString(string)
            let first = tuple.0 as NSData?
            if first != nil {
                return first!
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is when I set the password of the user like so: `user.password = "somepassword"`, the password should automatically be encrypted and returned as `NSData` using my `Utils.encryptString()` function (which is built on top of `RNEncryptor`). Then when I retrieve the value for that attribute, it should give me back the `NSData` object. Instead my transformer subclass never gets called and the password attribute remains as a string in clear text which I definitely do not want to send to my server.

I have the value transformer specified both in my CoreData model file and registered as a value transformed in my `NSManagedObject` subclass so I know that's not the issue. Is there any reason that when I set the password as a string, it doesn't automatically get converted? Is the value transformed only used when saving into a core data context and not whenever someone tries to access that property?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the value transformed only used when saving into a core data context and not whenever someone tries to access that property?

That's correct. The purpose of value transformers is to convert objects in memory to a different kind of object in the persistent store file. Usually that means converting some kind of object Core Data doesn't handle directly into an `NSData` when saving and reversing the process when loading the data. Transformers don't affect the in memory property values of your objects.

In short,

- Value transformers only work when saving changes
- A non reversible value transformer doesn't make sense with a Core Data property.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So I really should just set the attribute type to be binary data and convert it back and forth between encrypted and unencrypted myself.

Comment: If you never want to have the raw password in memory, that's correct.